# How do I get scrolling wallpaper through google wallpaper app on Galaxy J7?

Tags: live-wallpaper

I use Google's Wallpaper App for new wallpapers everyday. However, I am not getting scrolling wallpapers. I have gone through the complete settings of my device but it didn't find anything interesting?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KUBu4fXjhI) an app that allows you to do that, called *[Landscape Wallpaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lwp.superluminar.swallpaper&hl=en)*

I believe there are other apps that also allows you to do that, like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blackbirdwallpapers.landscapes&hl=en) and [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wallpapers4all.landscapewallpapers&hl=en). You can be free to choose (I, particularly, don't use any of these).